# How does this recursive function works, is it about computation structures?

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, tree

I'm working with a tree traversal code, I have been given the pseudocode, and I implemented it in python, but I still can't figure out how it works

```
InOrderTraversal(tree):
  if tree = nil:
     return
  InOrderTraversal(tree.left)
  Print(tree.key)
  InOrderTraversal(tree.right)
```

the pseudocode is shown above:
InOrderTraversal(tree.left): this code find the most left node of the tree, I thought it then stop there. But how does it coulde back to it's parent? and traverse the all nodes of the tree. it's can go back the nodes, that is what I'm confused, is that about some inner structure of computer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you call a function it remembers where it was called from and then returns when it is done, so it returns to its parent because it was called there and returns there when it is done. Just take a simple tree and consider what would happen step by step.

From the code I assume this is for a binary tree (where each node can only have two children)? Take A tree like this https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Sorted_binary_tree_preorder.svg#/media/File:Sorted_binary_tree_preorder.svg which happens to show the order you algorithm would go with the line surrounding it. 
It starts at the top with F as value for tree, 
calls the same function again with B 
which calls the same function with A. 
A has no child so its two InOrderTraversal calls trigger if tree = nil and immediately return
With that the function called with A as tree also reaches the end of its function block and returns to the function that called it. So we are now back at node B. There the code continues and it goes to the node D because the second InOrderTraversal is for the right node.

And so on, just go through it step by step in your head and it should become clear. (Or with a debugger if necessary.)

> InOrderTraversal(tree.left): this code find the most left node of the tree,

Tree.left is simply the left child of the current node, the function call will traverse the left child and all its children.

Answer (score 0):

The pseudocode above iterates over a [Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)), which a data structure.

Recursive functions are the functions, that call itself till the termination condition is met.

In a tree, there is one root node, and that will have a left child and a right child, each child may have a similar right and left Childs ( or may not have or have either left or right child).

If let's say any of the child (or root) does not have the right child, then the right child will be null, the same is true for left child.

So the above code is calling itself two times, once to iterate over the left branch and second to iterate over the right branch.

I will try to explain in simple language, instead of using lots of technical terms and confusing concepts, (kept is simple):

let's talk about left-only branch (for ex),

assume it is like A-B-C-D-E

now, the `A is root`, the first function call will call with `A as ref`, as it's left child is not equal to null (i.e has children), it will now call `InOrderTraversal` with A's child i.e. `B as ref`, meanwhile our function call with A's ref is stored in `call-stack`,

and again, B's child is C, which is also not null, so function `InOrderTraversal` is called again with `C's ref`, and `call-stack` will store the ref to function call with B's ref,

at this moment out call stack looks like this

```
 InOrderTraversal(C)
 InOrderTraversal(B)
 InOrderTraversal(A)
```

so it goes on till E, now E does not have child, so it will return to the function which called him, i.e. to function call with D's ref, which then return again back, and finally, we will come to main function call, which generated this all function calls.

The same goes for the right branch.

So this is possible with **`call-stack`**.

I tried to explain the part that is confusing to you.

I hope this helps you understand it.